# Finding the height of a regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

> The length of an edge of a regular tetrahedron is $8cm$. Find the total area of surfaces and the volume

I've been able to find the area of all surfaces, which is $(4\times27.713) cm^2$ but I'm not able to find the volume.

> There's no height given. How can I derive the height?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

the heights in the base are crossing each other in the ratio $1:2$ exactly under the top.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of a regular tetrahedron with side $a$ is given by

$V = \frac {a^3} {6 \sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @Brahadeesh it answers the Y part of an XY question. The problem is "Find the total area of surfaces and the volume".

Comment: fair enough... but a little more explanation would help improve the answer. The OP wants to know about the height of a tetrahedron given the side length.

Comment: @Brahadeesh it's a possible duplicate question anyway, please see my comment below the question.

Comment: thank you for searching it out, I’ve added my vote to close as duplicate based on the link.